# Problem with aop subtractor with simple power supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I am using a LM324 with a simple power supply like you can see in the picture below as a subtractor.

[image: Subtractor]

It subtracts \$Vs = V1 - V2\$, and my problem is, when the subtraction is positive I have no problem but when it's negative I thought I would have 0V but I always get 0.6V wathever the result of the negative subtraction is. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with the LM324 is that if you are taking any significant pull-up current you get 0.6 volts or higher as the minimum voltage the output can drop to: -

[image]

And I bet you are thinking reading this "but I'm not taking any pull-up current". Well, in fact you are - the negative feedback resistor and input resistor to your "V2" signal are pulling-up the output. The two series 8.2 kohm resistors are pulling the output up to V2 and possibly forcing over 100 uA into the output.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, so does that mean the LM324 is not suited for this application ? i should choose an aop with better feature? maybe LM358 ?

Comment: Firstly, you will never get 0 volts out of any op-amp when the lowest power rail is 0 volts however, if you changed the resistors from 8k2 to 820 k ohm you might get close to 10 mV and this may be OK for you. Even so-called rail-to-rail op-amps struggle to get less than 10 mV.

Comment: ah you're right sorry, i didn't notice it. by the way, didn't work with 560K resistor, i still have 0.6V .

Comment: so i will try to use an rail-to-rail aop and see if i can get closer to 0V.

Comment: @lawir it should work with a rail-to-rail opamp.

Comment: @ Andy aka, can you give me a reference of an op rail-to-rail ?

Comment: The only quad package that springs to mind is the AD8608 - it can get to within 40 mV of 0 volts with a 1 mA pull-up current. Also available in single and dual.

Comment: and what about a dual package ?

Comment: Yeah that's covered if you look up the 8608 data sheet (it's called the 8606 from memory).

Comment: @ Andy aka, thank you very much, i learned a lot. i tried with a LM358 and the results was amazing, 25mA at the output, problem sloved.

Comment: That is a surprise because I believed that the LM358 was the same as the LM324 regarding output being dragged up. Maybe the old grey cells are playing up LOL.